# How do you create a line break in Doxygen markdown?

Tags: doxygen, doxywizard

I'm having a hard time locating the documentation explaining how to add a line break in Doxygen markdown.

I've tried using two spaces at the end of the line, and I've also tried a single or double newline, but none of these are working for me.

I'm using Doxygen version 1.8.9.1.

Comment: Did you try \n followed by a space or <br>

Comment: @albert Thanks, both of those work! I'm still hoping there is some other way, or something I was doing wrong, because using things like html or escape sequences in Markdown sort of defeats the point of using markdown.

Answer (score 16):

Put a HTML-break tag `<br>` where you want to have a linebreak, does the job.
At least for man page output and HTML output.

Comment: If I do this in a `\par`, I get the warning "warning: Illegal command n as part of a title section" (Doxygen 1.8.14).

Comment: Emacs interprets literal `<br>` in weird ways - be warned!

Answer (score 9):

Add `\n` followed by a space at the end of your line [1].

Especially recommended when editing with Emacs, which reacts in weird ways to the other suggested solution `<br>`.

[1] As per @albert's comment. Works for me under Doxygen 1.8.13.

Comment: current version is 1.8.15 maybe you can check in 1.8.15 as well (I expect that it will work there as well)